# VisualG - duvidas sobre como fazer parar

Tags: visualg

Bom dia, estou fazendo um código que ele recebe quantos moradores eu quero cadastrar e qual a idade, porém se eu digito que quero cadastrar apenas um, ele pede a idade e retorna novamente a pergunta. Gostaria de saber, como faço para ele parar de perguntar a idade de acordo com o tanto de morador que quero cadastrar. 
Por exemplo: se quero cadastrar 2, ele tem que me perguntar apenas duas vezes a idade do morador. 
Var

```
// Seção de Declarações das variáveis 
Cont, EleitorObrigatorio, EleitorFacultativo, NaoEleitor, idade, i : Inteiro

Inicio
// Seção de Comandos, procedimento, funções, operadores, etc... 
Escreval ("Quantas pessoas quer cadastrar? ")
Leia (Cont)
i <- 1
Enquanto (i = Cont) faca

Escreval ("Digite a idade do morador? ")

Leia (Idade)

se ((idade >= 18) e (idade <= 70)) entao

EleitorObrigatorio <- EleitorObrigatorio + 1

 Escreval (EleitorObrigatorio, " são eleitores obrigatórios")

senao

se ((idade >= 16) e (idade <= 17) ou (idade >= 71)) entao

EleitorFacultativo <- EleitorFacultativo + 1

 Escreval (EleitorFacultativo, " são eleitores facultativos")

senao

se (idade <= 15) entao

NaoEleitor <- NaoEleitor + 1

 Escreval (EleitorFacultativo, " não são eleitores")

Fimse

FimSe

FimSe


FimEnquanto


Fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0):

Inicialize seus acumuladores. O teste no "enquanto" está errado. Imprima as totalizações apenas ao final.

```
algoritmo "Exercício"
Var
    Cont, EleitorObrigatorio, EleitorFacultativo, NaoEleitor, idade, i : Inteiro
Inicio
    EleitorObrigatorio <- 0
    EleitorFacultativo <- 0
    NaoEleitor <- 0
    Escreval ("Quantas pessoas quer cadastrar? ")
    Leia (Cont)
    i <- 1
    Enquanto (i <= Cont) faca
        Escreval ("Digite a idade do morador? ")
        Leia (Idade)
        se ((idade >= 18) e (idade <= 70)) entao
            EleitorObrigatorio <- EleitorObrigatorio + 1
        senao
            se ((idade >= 16) e (idade <= 17) ou (idade >= 71)) entao
                EleitorFacultativo <- EleitorFacultativo + 1
            senao
                se (idade <= 15) entao
                    NaoEleitor <- NaoEleitor + 1
                Fimse
            FimSe
        FimSe
    FimEnquanto
    Escreval (EleitorObrigatorio, " são eleitores obrigatórios")
    Escreval (EleitorFacultativo, " são eleitores facultativos")
    Escreval (NaoEleitor, " não são eleitores")
Fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Mesmo fazendo assim, ele ainda está no looping e não aparece mais quantos são eleitores e etc

Comment: Faltou um `i < i + 1` antes do `FimEnquanto`.

Comment: Funcionou!!! Muito obrigada

Comment: @JéssicaAlmeida não esqueça de marcar a resposta como "Resolvido" para ajudar a comunidade a saber se tal pergunta foi ajudada (:

Comment: Uma observação adicional: como é para iterar um número fixo de vezes (`cont`) em minha opinião fica mais claro utilizar o comando `para i de 1 ate cont faca` no lugar do `enquanto`.